# Saving month name and year from Ajax Calender into SQL Server 2005 DateTime Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a simple Asp.NET webform with a TextBox. I have attached an AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender to this TextBox to provide for Calendar functionality. I have set the CalenderExtender format property to "MMMM" such that the calender by default will display months rather than month days.

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:
I have a table with a `StartMonth` column whose datatype is `DateTime`. When the user selects say June or October from the calendar, I want to save that month in this `DateTime` column but unfortunately, strings "June" or "October, ....." can not be saved in a `DateTime` column.

How should implement this better?, I want to store the month name and year, I'm not interested in the day part.

Comment: ignore the day part, say it be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i take this as the answer to my question.

http://www.aghausman.net/asp/how-to-show-and-select-monthyear-in-calendar-extender.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't store a datetime without having a day. Just use the first day of the month and don't act on it.

```
Declare @month Varchar(12),
@year Char(4)
SET @month = 'october'
SET @year = 2011
SELECT Cast('1'+@month+@year as smalldatetime)
```

Sql server 2008

```
SELECT Cast('1'+@month+@year as date)
```

Comment: ok, that will actually help me, but in the Calendar text box, a user selects a month, then the calendar drills down to the days in the selected month. If any day is clicked, the month name is then set as the value of the Textbox bacause of my "MMMM" format. But since the month name is a string i can't save it in the DateTime field. So if the user selects any day in November, i will have "November" in the Calendar  Textbox, and i'm wondering if it might be possible to just save 2011-11-01 when i have the string 'November' as the selected month in the calendar Textbox?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior replace october with november in my example and that is what you have.

Comment: i have gone with this implementation  http://www.aghausman.net/asp/how-to-show-and-select-monthyear-in-calendar-extender.html